# automapper for php?

Tags: php, .net

Are there any .Net automapper equivalent libraries but for php?

i.e. something that will copy all info from one class to another, for example `user` <-> `userDTO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Yes there are! I wrote a little rudimentary library, which can be downloaded here: http://automapper.nylle.de

---

**Original answer:** 
I haven't heard of it, but I assume this to be rather unlikely, since PHP does not support return types for methods or functions. How can you possibly map the properties of two different classes, if you can only reflect their names, but not their types?

You could still write a little static helper class that simply gets two flat objects and copies all values from one property to the other class' property with the same name using [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), but this will only work, if you know what you do and the types are convertable (like [scalar types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) string/int/bool).

Maybe you can put some more reliability into it by [parsing the `phpdoc` part](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) (if available) to get a clue about the return type.